# Prevent passing a new function as a prop in a functional component that uses useState

Tags: reactjs, closures, react-hooks

I know that passing a new function every render as a prop to a react component can affect performance (for example passing an arrow function). In a class component I usually solve this problem by passing a method of the class.
But say we have a functional component that uses say `useState` and I want to create a closure that calls a function returned from `useState`. This function will be created anew every render, so whatever component it is passed to will be rerendered. Is there a way to avoid passing a new function that refers to some variable, function inside of a functional component?

```
import React from 'react'
import IDontWantToRerender from './heavyComputations';

export default function IneffectiveFunctionalComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const valueChanger = () => {
    setValue(Math.random());
  }
  return (
    <IDontWantToRerender valueChanger={valueChanger} value={value} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)  hook.

```
const valueChanger = useCallback(
    () => {
        setValue(Math.random());
    },[setValue]); // you need some other dependencies for when it should change
```

As said in the comments

> I wonder, is it really necessary to pass setValue as it will not change?

Yes, if you take a look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), it says

> **Note**
>
> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the callback. Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: every value referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies array. In the future, a sufficiently advanced compiler could create this array automatically.
>
> We recommend using the exhaustive-deps rule as part of our eslint-plugin-react-hooks package. It warns when dependencies are specified incorrectly and suggests a fix.

Comment: I wonder, is it really necessary to pass `setValue` as it will not change?

Comment: @Alvaro Yes, check the edit please. You could add other dependencies too, but it depends on your case